# Program reading only 2 lines

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop

I have i problem. I want my program to calculate numbers. I need to input multiple lines, then after *CTRL+Z* evaluate all of it. But instead it works only for first line. Also i have with dividing by zero. Dont know when i should make a if statmet to stop program when 0 is typed.

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "evalexpression.h"

int main() {
    char string[100];
    int result;
    while(fgets(string, sizeof(string),stdin))
        {
            result = InterCalc(string, sizeof(string));
            Calc(result, string);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

tols.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>
#include "evalexpression.h"

static float f1, f2;
static char op;

int isValidExpression(const char *str)
{
    int res;
    char ops[10];
    while()
    res=sscanf(str, "%f %s %f", &f1, ops, &f2);
    if (res==3) {
        if (ops[0]=='+' || ops[0]=='-' || ops[0]=='^' || ops[0]=='*' || ops[0]=='/')
            {
                op=ops[0];
                return 1;
            }
            else return 0;
    }
    else return 0;
}

int getOperator()
{
    return(op);
}

float getFstOperand()
{
    return(f1);
}

float getSecOperand()
{
    return(f2);
}

float getExprValue() {
    switch (getOperator()) {
    case '+':
        return getFstOperand() + getSecOperand();
    case '-':
        return getFstOperand() - getSecOperand();
    case '/':
        return getFstOperand() / getSecOperand();
    case '*':
        return getFstOperand() * getSecOperand();
    case '^':
        return pow(getFstOperand(), getSecOperand());
    default:
        return 0;
    }
}

int InterCalc(char *my_string, int size) {
    if (fgets(my_string, size, stdin) == NULL ||  strcmp(my_string, "exit\n") == 0) {
        printf("Program ended\n");
        return 0;
    } else
    if (isValidExpression(my_string) == 0) {
        printf("Expression error\n");
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

void Calc(int a, char *str)
{
    float calculation_value;
        if (a==1) {
            calculation_value = getExprValue();
            printf("The result of %s is %f\n", str, calculation_value);
        }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you read until EOF instead and have CTRL-D be the terminator as it normally is.

Comment: Why do you call `fgets` in `main` and again in `InterCalc`?

Comment: @EliSadoff  I tried different approaches to do so, but none of it worked

Comment: @WeatherVane That what left after trying diffrent things

Comment: "But instead it works only for first line." is not detailed enough.  What was the input of all lines, all the output and in the case of lines after the first, what was the expected output?

Comment: Did you do something like `"1+2"`, which certainly will not work with `"%f %s %f"`?  I suspect you wanted `"%f %1s %f"`, but without seeing sample input - who knows?  Providing sample input helps us all.

Comment: `while()` is not even valid code.  Post your true code.

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Your code contains "left-overs" and at least one syntax error - the line `while()`.

Comment: After removing that `while()` and the extra `fgets` the program compiles, although the compiler warns that you should be using the `double` type not `float`. Far from working "twice" the program keeps on taking input and printing the answer (but see @chux comment about the input format). So MCVE with the *specific* problem please. Although the program does not end on "exit" because the code to make it end is not followed through.